# adding mutiple audio file in android

Tags: android, audio

i'm adding multiple audio files using

```
    try {
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.play);
        audioArr[0] = mp;
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mp.start();

            }
        });

        mp.prepare();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and releasing media in a function as

```
for (MediaPlayer media : audioList) {
        if (media != null) {
            if(media.isPlaying())
            media.stop();
            media.release();
            media = null;
        }
    }
```

stil i'm not able to play multiple audio file in my application,first time playing with audio,so kindly guide

Comment: Do you want to queue the audio files as playlist or play all simultaneously...? If first then add next file to play in onComplete callback. And If second case need to go with SoundPool rather than MediaPlayer

Comment: thanx,I want to play  after completion of some event,like some animation etc.pl give me some example i'm using it for first time

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
void addSongs()
{
    File songs = new File(sdPath); //sdPath is the path of your audio files

    if(songs.listFiles(new SongFilter()).length > 0)
    {
        for(File file : songs.listFiles(new SongFilter()))

        {
            vector.add(file.getName());
        }

        arrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true); //arrayAdapter Array Adapter
        songList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); //songList is a ListView
    }
}
```

SongFilter Class like this :

```
class SongFilter implements FilenameFilter
{
    public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) 
    {
        return (filename.endsWith(".mp3"));
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
buttonSound.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
// play another sound here.do your stuff whatever you want to do
mp.stop();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class AudioActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
         int [] songs;
         MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
         int current_index = 0; 
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {##}
        private void start(){
            songs= new int[] {R.raw.s1,R.raw.s2,R.raw.s3,R.raw.s4};
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, songs[0]);
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
**// This is the completion listener registered with mediaplayer instance.**            
playNextSong();
        }
         private void playNextSong()
            {
                current_index = (current_index +1)% songs.length;
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = this.getResources().openRawResourceFd(songs[current_index]);
                if(current_index!=0){
                try
                {   
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    afd.close();
                }
                catch (IllegalArgumentException e){}
                catch (IllegalStateException e){}
                catch (IOException e){}
             }else{
                 mediaPlayer.stop(); 
             }
            }


    }
```